# MIPS subroutine that prints the time in minutes and seconds after a given starting time

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I am trying to create a MIPS assembly program that "prints the time". The starting time is initialized to `0x5957` (which stands for 59 minutes and 57 seconds) in the variable `mytime`. The program is then supposed to repeatedly increment the time by 1 second and print it to the I/O window in the format `59:57`. For example, if the time is initialized to `0x5957` the expected output of 5 loops is

```
59:58
59:59
60:00
60:01
60:02
```

I have written a partially working program, but it goes wrong when incremented by 1 second when the time is `59:59`. When initialized with the time value `0x5957` and allowed to loop its output is

```
59:58
59:59
09:00
09:01
09:02
   ⋮
09:58
09:59
09:00
09:01
```

My full program can be seen below.

```
    .data
    .align 2
mytime: .word 0x5957
timstr: .ascii "text more text lots of text\0"
    .text
main:
    # print timstr
    la  $a0,timstr
    li  $v0,4
    syscall
    nop
    # wait a little
    li  $a0,2
    jal delay
    nop
    # call tick
    la  $a0,mytime
    jal tick
    nop
    # call your function time2string
    la  $a0,timstr
    la  $t0,mytime
    lw  $a1,0($t0)
    jal time2string
    nop
    # print a newline
    li  $a0,10
    li  $v0,11
    syscall
    nop
    # go back and do it all again
    j   main
    nop
# tick: update time pointed to by $a0
tick:   lw  $t0,0($a0)  # get time
    addiu   $t0,$t0,1   # increase
    andi    $t1,$t0,0xf # check lowest digit
    sltiu   $t2,$t1,0xa # if digit < a, okay
    bnez    $t2,tiend
    nop
    addiu   $t0,$t0,0x6 # adjust lowest digit
    andi    $t1,$t0,0xf0    # check next digit
    sltiu   $t2,$t1,0x60    # if digit < 6, okay
    bnez    $t2,tiend
    nop
    addiu   $t0,$t0,0xa0    # adjust digit
    andi    $t1,$t0,0xf00   # check minute digit
    sltiu   $t2,$t1,0xa00   # if digit < a, okay
    bnez    $t2,tiend
    nop
    addiu   $t0,$t0,0x600   # adjust digit
    andi    $t1,$t0,0xf000  # check last digit
    sltiu   $t2,$t1,0x6000  # if digit < 6, okay
    bnez    $t2,tiend
    nop
    addiu   $t0,$t0,0xa000  # adjust last digit
tiend:  sw  $t0,0($a0)  # save updated result
    jr  $ra     # return
    nop

# Returns an ASCII code to $v0 for one of the characters 0-9 or A-F based on the value of
# the four least significant bits of $a0. The mapping between the value of the four least
# significant digits of $a0 and the characters 0-9 and A-F is: {(0, 0), (1, 1), ... (15, F)}.
hexasc: 
    # $a0 = $a0 & 0xF
    # if ($a0 > 9) $v0 = $a0 + 0x37
    # else $v0 = $a0 + 0x30

    addi    $t1, $0, 9      # $t1 = 9 (bound between numbers and letters)
    andi    $a0, $a0, 0xF       # 28 zeros concatinated with the last 4 bits of $a0             

    bgt     $a0, $t1, gt9       # branch to gt9, if $a0 > 9

    addi    $v0, $a0, 0x30      # convert $a0 to ascii code for 0-9
    jr  $ra             

gt9:
    addi $v0, $a0, 0x37     # convert $a0 to ascii code for A-F
    jr $ra

delay:
    jr $ra
    nop

# $a0 = memory address for time2string output
# $a1 = The 16 least significant bits contain time-info, organized as four NBCD-coded 
#   digits of 4-bits. 16 most significant bits are arbitrary
# return value: none
#
# time2string writes the following sequence of six characters to the area in
# memory pointed to by $a0, IN THE GIVEN ORDER:
#   1. Two ASCII-coded digits showing the number of minutes, according to
#      the two most significant NBCD-coded digits of $a1.
#   2. A colon character. 
#   3. Two ASCII-coded digits showing the number of seconds, according to
#      the two least significant NBCD-coded digits of $a1.
#   4. A null byte.
time2string:
    # Extract NBCD-coded minutes/seconds from $a1.
    andi    $t0, $a1, 0xF000    # $t0 = zeros concat with most significant
    sra $t0, $t0, 12        # NBCD-coded digit (tens of minutes)
    andi    $t1, $a1, 0xF00     # $t1 = zeros contact with second most significant
    sra $t1, $t1, 8     # NBCD-coded digit (minutes)
    andi    $t2, $a1, 0xF0      # t2 = zeros concat with second lest significant
    sra     $t2, $t2, 4     # NBCD-coded digit (tens of seconds)
    andi    $t3, $a1, 0xF       # t3 = zeros concat with least significant
                    # NBCD-coded digit (seconds)

    # Save necessery overwritten constants.
    move    $t4, $a0        # $t4 = memory address for time2string output
    move    $t5, $ra        # $t5 = return address to main

    # Convert NBCD-coded minutes/seconds to ASCII-coded digits.
    # Arrange ASCII-coded minutes/seconds into the above specified sequence of
    # characters in the area of memory pointed to by $t4 = $a0.
    move    $a0, $t0    # a0 = NBCD-coded tens of minutes digit
    jal hexasc      # $v0 = ASCII-coded tens of minutes digit
    nop
    sb  $v0, 0($t4) # store 8 least significant bits of $v0 at mem[reg($t4)]

    move    $a0, $t1    # $a0 = NBCD-coded minutes digit
    jal hexasc      # $v0 = ASCII-coded minutes digit
    nop
    sb  $v0, 1($t4) # store 8 least significant bits of $v0 at 
                # mem[reg($t4 + sgnxt(1)]

    li  $t6, 0x3A   # $t6 = ASCII-code for colon
    sb  $t6, 2($t4) # store 8 least significant bits of $t6 at
                # mem[reg($t4 + sgnxt(2)]               

    move    $a0, $t2    # $a0 = NBCD-coded tens of seconds digit
    jal hexasc      # $v0 = ASCII-coded tens of seconds digit
    nop
    sb  $v0, 3($t4) # store 8 least significant bits of $v0 at
                # mem[reg($t4 + sgnxt(2)]

    move    $a0, $t3    # $a0 = NBCD-coded seconds digit
    jal hexasc      # $v0 = ASCII-coded seconds digit
    nop
    sb  $v0, 4($t4) # store 8 least significant bits of $v0 at
                # mem[reg($t4 + sgnxt(3)]

    li  $t6, 0x00   # $t6 = ASCII-code for NUL
    sb  $t6, 5($t4) 

    jr  $t5
```

I suspect that the error may stem from the `time2string` subroutine, but I have not been able to pin point the source of the problem. Any help to resolve this issue is appreciated.

Comment: Your `hexasc` uses `$t1` internally but you saved the second digit there so it gets destroyed. PS: learn to use a debugger/simulator so you can step through the code and find your own mistakes.

Comment: @Jester Thanks for helping me find the error. This sure fixed it.